# Elastic Beanstalk: Container Command not copying file

Tags: tomcat, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

so I have the following .config in my .ebextensions direcory. It's a tomcat8 environment:

```
    container_commands: 
  replace-web_xml: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/web.xml /etc/tomcat8/web.xml
  replace-config: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/insign.properties /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/insign.properties
```

Now replace-web_xml is working fine,only the replace-config command isn't working. The file is not being copied to that location. I've looked into the log but couldnt find anything that could cause this.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: any luck with this? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, and so far all attempts have failed with little log to indicate where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled onto this now. Even if it's ages old, someone might need the answer. The problem is that since there is no cwd specified, the command is run from / by default. You need to set `cwd` as an instruction just above `command` to be able to run the command in the question. The directory to be set depends on the language used for your application. I haven't been able to find an actual list that specifies this. I would use ssh to login to an instance and see where the application is located.